# Literature Request: Stochastic Calculus

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-calculus

Hello does can anyone tell me what is required to learn Stochastic Differential Equations? Anybody have any really good resources that make learning the subject easy?

Also is it true that not many such equations have been solved? I read somewhere that it was almost futile to learn it since very few equations have been solved and no one used the either way. Is this all true?

I am deeply interested in the subject, but I only know up to Differential equations and a few methods in solving PDEs

Comment: How much probability do you know? For example, enough to study the definition/properties of Brownian motion?

Comment: I've only read about it. I know the definitions. I understand what the process is describing but I have never attempted a problem.

Comment: Get Brownian motion in place, first. It is very important

Comment: Sure of course. What would be a viable plan? I have read books that say real analysis is required although, I don't really seem to get why this is so?

Comment: Yes, because you will be dealing with $C([0,1])$ and $L^p$ spaces in your study. Which textbook are you using? Also, how much real analysis do you know?

Comment: I just started Real Analysis here 
http://www.math.louisville.edu/~lee/RealAnalysis/

Comment: I think you will need measure theory as well, to go with the page you attached, but the real analysis course will be helpful.

Comment: @JonathanAguilera it is a good idea to get a firm understanding of measure theory. I would put off probability theory until you understand it. The canonical book for stochastic differential equations at an introductory level is the book by bert oksendal

Answer (score 0):

Try the MIT Open Courseware lectures on youtube:

https:///ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-s096-topics-in-mathematics-with-applications-in-finance-fall-2013/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out [An Introduction to Stochastic Differential Equations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1470410540) by Evans. It's only 150 pages and appears to be rather readable. Evans's book Partial Differential Equations has become very popular for graduate level PDEs courses.